# Get 400 error after submitting form C# MVC .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

In my application, i want to submit my form and post the data into the method in my controller.
The controller looks like this:

```
public IActionResult Toevoegen()
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Toevoegen(Customer customer)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      var cust = customer;
      return RedirectToAction("Toevoegen");
   }
   else
      return View();
}
```

The form looks like this:

```
@model Customer

<h2>Create</h2>

<form class="m-1 p-1" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="CompanyName"></label>
        <input asp-for="CompanyName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="CompanyName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="Email" type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Tel"></label>
        <input asp-for="Tel" type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Tel" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="City"></label>
        <input asp-for="City" type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I've added `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` in my _ViewImports.

When I go to the "toevoegen" page, I keep getting the 400 error.

Did some research and I found something about the validateantiforgerytoken.

Does someone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Any exceptions thrown and visible in the output window(assuming you are using VS)?

Comment: Have you inspected you response to ensure the anti-forgery token is in the header?

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, the tokens are added to your forms automatically. Can you see the hidden input with the anti-forgery token in your form?